# Альтернатива jQuery на чистом JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {

  var lastPage = location.pathname;
  var lastUrl = (lastPage == '/') || (lastPage == '/index.html') ? '/main.html' : lastPage;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', lastUrl, true);

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  };

  request.send();
});
```

Но мне нельзя использовать jQuery, попытался найти альтернативы на чистом JavaScript для:

`$(window).bind('popstate', function() {...});`

и

```
$('a').click(function() { 
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  ...
});
```

Но ничего не нашел, help!

Comment: `window.addEventListener('popstate', function(){});`

Comment: @Deonis, Да! Это оно) Спасибо. Вот еще вопрос есть небольшой... Код: `$('a').click(function() { var href = $(this).attr('href'); ...});` Задача таже, help please :-)

Comment: `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // если надо отменить действие по умолчанию
    // ваш код тут
  }, false);
});`

Comment: @Deonis, да.. Это уже покруче будет) А вот тут ключевой момент, чем var href = $(this).attr('href'); заменить?

Comment: `var href = this.getAttribute('href');`

Comment: Я же вам написал: `e.preventDefault(); // если надо отменить действие по умолчанию `

Comment: @Deonis, ой, не сразу понял) Спасибо большое!

Comment: Cash - небольшая библиотека для современных браузеров - [Альтернатива jQuery](https://github.com/kenwheeler/cash/)

Comment: @Deonis, стоит оформить комментарии ответом :-)

Comment: Спасибо, но мне вообще нельзя использовать сторонних библиотек. Решение уже было найдено.

Comment: @Grundy, Привет :) Да, было бы неплохо...

Comment: @ProstoJohn, наверное стоит и дополнительные вопросы из комментариев в сам вопрос добавить

Comment: @Grundy, добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аналогом функции [*bind*](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) и более новой функции [*on*](http://api.jquery.com/on/) в jQuery можно считать функцию [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(){...});
```

Для изменения второго участка кода, необходимо разобраться **что именно** он делает:

1. выбирает все элементы `<a>`
2. добавляет каждому обработчик события `click`
3. в обработчике получается значение `href`

Для получения всех элементов `<a>` можно использовать функции [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) и [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
```

Далее нужно обойти все элементы и добавить им обработчик с помощью функции [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
for(var i=0,len=aTags.length; i<len; i++){
    aTags[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        ...
    });
}
```

Для получения `href` можно использовать либо метод [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) либо свойство [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href)

```
var href = this.href;
```

Итоговый пример:

```
var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for(var i=0,len=aTags.length; i<len; i++){
    aTags[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var href = this.href;
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все наглядно и по полочкам :-)

Comment: Только вот вопрос, чем плох такой метод решения?: `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(el) { el.addEventListener('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); // если надо отменить действие по умолчанию // ваш код тут }, false); });` Тоже все работает

Comment: @ProstoJohn, а я где-то сказал что он плох? :-) я просто привел другой вариант :-)

Comment: А ну я понял :)